# how to change package name in numerous places in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to change Package Name of Flutter project?  I want to change package name and application name in flutter project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this pub. dev package for changing package names in all places.

https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name

```
dev_dependencies: 
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
```